# 開発者コマンド プロンプト for VS 2017に依存ライブラリを追加する

Tags: c++, visual-studio

開発者コマンド プロンプト for VS 2017で直接ビルドしたいプロジェクトがあるのですが、
依存ライブラリが見つからずにリンクエラーになります。
ライブラリ自体は持ってるのですが、開発者コマンドにそれをリンクさせるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

ビルドしたいプロジェクトはMRuby2.0.1で、依存ライブラリはonigmo_s.libです。

Comment: 「依存ライブラリを追加する」とはどのような結果を求められているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

コマンドプロンプトでサードパーティライブラリをリンクしたい IDE は使わない
であるものと解釈しました。

`Makefile` なり `msbuild` なりで、リンクを行う段階に `link.exe` に対するオプションを追加します。ないしは `#pragma comment(lib, "...lib")` をソース中に記述します。

ライブラリの追加リンク指定：ライブラリ名を直接指定します。

```
link <いろいろ指定１> onigmo_s.lib <いろいろ指定２>
```

ライブラリのディレクトリ指定：コマンドライン `/LIBPATH:<dir>` を追加します。

```
link /LIBPATH:"C:\projects\onigmo"
```

あるいは

```
cl <いろいろ> /LINK /LIBPATH:"C:\projects\onigmo"
```